# Using jQuery with Matlab

Tags: jquery, api, matlab

I am planning on using this [API](http://www3.septa.org/hackathon/) to get a train schedule using Matlab, but the API uses jQuery. Does anyone have any ways of going about using this jQuery API with Matlab? I found [THIS](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab-a-toolbox-to-encodedecode-json-files-in-matlaboctave), but I wouldnt know how to attach my Matlab variables to the jQuery code. Any help, ideas, suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API documentation only gives jQuery as an example, you can use matlab's urlread

User urlread http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html
then json parser http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20565 or the one you give

Answer (score 1):

Could this be helpful? [MATLAB, jQuery and JSON](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/linkexchange/links/2377-matlab-jquery-and-json)

Comment: I already looked at that but I wouldnt know how to use the Matlab variables I have inside the jQuery code